# dataset vs .data - Difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset, custom-data-attribute

I am reading some values in data attribute fields. I have seen two easy ways to read the data as shown below:

```
var webappData = document.getElementById('web-app-data'),
    rating = webappData.dataset.rating;
```

OR

```
var effectData = $('.effects-list li'),
    creative = effectData.filter('[data-creative]').data("creative");
```

My question is which of these has better performance or do they really differ?

I have a page with many data attributes that I am accessing and I would like to use the method that has the best performance.

Any guidance on understanding the difference between the two would be appreciated. While I am looking at performance specifically if there are other reasons to use one over the other I would like to know this as well.

Comment: I'd say pure JS is faster or equal to jQuery

Comment: Since .dataset is pure Javascript I suppose it should be faster than using .data() (after all, at least you're missing one function call), although the difference is probably a few milliseconds.

The only thing you always have to consider is that not every browser knows .dataset. Refer here for the browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) is a native property of an element that contains the data attributes, it's a new(ish) addition and as such is only supported in IE11+, Chrome 8+, FF 6+ etc.

A more cross browser solution would be to get the attribute directly

```
webappData.getAttribute('data-rating');
```

---

[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is a jQuery method, and other than using the HTML5 data attribute to set the inital value if none exists internally, it has nothing in common with dataset.

`data()` stores whatever data you pass it in an internal object created by jQuery, so this for instance would fail

```
$(element).data('key', 'value');

element.dataset.key // undefined
```

as the data is not stored in the attributes at all, but internally by jQuery.
The jQuery equivalent of getting and setting the data attribute would be `attr()`

```
$(element).attr('data-key', 'value');
```

---

The native methods are probably faster, but as they are not really comparable to jQuery's `data()` it doesn't really matter, but for getting the data attribute I would think the fastest method with the best browser support would be

```
var rating = webappData.getAttribute('data-rating');
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Other than browser compatibility are there reasons to use `.getAttribute` over `.dataset`?

Comment: Indeed there are: My experience is that .dataset does not work in all browser (especially older IEs don't work)

Comment: btw: `As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.`

Comment: If you want to edit it into your answer, here's a JSPerf test showing `getAttribute` to be considerably faster than `dataset`: https://jsperf.com/dataset-vs-getattribute-and-setattribute/13

Comment: Values of `dataset` items are always strings, while jQuery's `data()` preserves types set by [`.data(key, value)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value). (`dataset` returns [`DOMStringMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap); jQuery's `data()` returns `jQuery` object.)