# Chosen updating the placeholder text when dynamically populating options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen and I'm dynamically loading options via an AJAX call. Everything works fine but I can't figure out how to change the placeholder text if the result of the AJAX call is empty.

So for example:

```
<select name="test" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Make a selection" 
    id=MyChosenSel"></select>
```

When nothing has been selected the box has a placeholder which reads "Make A Selection". I want to have this say "No options available" if the AJAX call returns `null`.

I expected this to work:

```
$('#MyChosenSel').data('placeholder',"No Options").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

To change the text placeholder for the select you should use the *placeholder_text* option in the chosen config for example use this:

```
$("#myChosen").chosen({
   placeholder_text:"my custom placeholder text"
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chosen 1.8.7 (possibly earlier, haven't tested it), the [`set_default_text`](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/v1.8.7/coffee/lib/abstract-chosen.coffee#L40) function, called by the `chosen:updated` event handler, specifically checks the `data-placeholder` attribute, not the jQuery data (which is what `.data("placeholder", ...)` sets). So, this is what you have to do:

```js
$("#MyChosenSel")
    .attr("data-placeholder", "No Options")
    .trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MyChosenSel").chosen({
  allow_single_deselect:true,
  disable_search_threshold: 10,
  no_results_text: "No options available",
  width: "25%"
});
```

Fiddle here to show you.....http://jsfiddle.net/mikeys4u/99Dkm/237/

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596838/152016) clarifies how to use jQuery to change the `data-placeholder` attribute on the `SELECT` tag.

In the code below you can see how to use either jQuery or the plain javascript `dataset` attribute of the `SELECT` to change the value of chosen select's placeholder.

Note that the key to access placeholder value in the `dataset` object is `placeholder` (instead of `data-placeholder`).

Hope that this benefits anybody.

```js
$('SELECT').chosen({width: '80%'});

$('BUTTON#jQuery').on('click', function() {
  $('SELECT').attr('data-placeholder', 'Placeholder updated with jQuery!');
  $('SELECT').trigger('chosen:updated');
});

$('BUTTON#dataset').on('click', function() {
  $('SELECT')[0].dataset['placeholder'] = 'Placeholder updated with dataset obj!';
  $('SELECT').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<SELECT data-placeholder="Placeholder before chosen:updated">
<OPTION></OPTION>
<OPTION>1</OPTION>
<OPTION>2</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<BUTTON id="jQuery">Click for updating placeholder with jQuery</BUTTON>

<BUTTON id="dataset">Click for updating placeholder with dataset hash</BUTTON>
```