# getting dataset value from a nodeList javascript

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I have a nodeList of div and each div has an img with src, id and a dataset. 
When looping the nodeList with a forEach loop I  store the first element of that div (hence the img) so i can then access to its id, src and dataset. I'm succeeding in getting the id and the src but not the dataset;  it always returns an empty DOMStringMap {} .

How can i get this info?

each div has an img like ->

```
        function getCards(){
            let totalCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card")

            totalCards.forEach(el => {

                el.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    let thisCard = el.children[0]
                    let thisCardID = thisCard.id
                    let thisCardDataSet = thisCard.dataset
                    let thisCardSRC = thisCard.src

                    console.log(thisCard)
                    console.log(thisCardID)
                    console.log(thisCardDataSet)
                    console.log(thisCardSRC)

                })

            })
            //console.log(flippedCard)
        }
´´´
```

Comment: U can understand better dataset here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23596838/11437287

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is an attribute of your `img` tag like so:

```
<img src=".." alt=".." dataset="..." />
```

Then you will need to grab the attributes object first

```
let thisCardDataSet = thisCard.attributes.dataset
```